# ionic framework tabs with ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs

I am building android app using ionic framework. I am facing issue by using the ionic tabs.

**ion-nav-view content not displaying using ng-repeat, but same is working with out using ng-repeat**. Tab title is displaying properly but tab content is showing blank.

### using ng-repeat

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
    <ion-tab ng-repeat="infotabs in customerInfo" title="{{infotabs.tabval}}" href="#/customerview/{{infotabs.tabname}}">
      <ion-nav-view name="customerview-{{infotabs.tabname}}"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
```

### without using ng-repeat

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
    <ion-tab title="General" href="#/customerview/General">
      <ion-nav-view name="customerview-General"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Employment" href="#/customerview/Employment">
      <ion-nav-view name="customerview-Employment"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Relationship" href="#/customerview/Relationship">
      <ion-nav-view name="customerview-Relationship"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
```

Comment: if possible create fiddle link.

Comment: may be it is related with this github thread https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1503