# Ionic dynamic tabs are not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in Ionic and AnguarJs. I have created a tab dynamically using ng-repeat. Tab title values are coming correct but tab content are incorrect.

Here is my code,

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-striped tabs-top theme-color">
<ion-tab ng-repeat="sub in subjects" title="{{sub.MockTestSubjectTitle}}">
    <ion-tab-content name="ion-{{sub.MockTestSubjectTitle}}">
        {{sub.MockTestSubjectTitle}}
    </ion-tab-content>  
</ion-tab>
```

Here tab titles are subject name eg: Physics, Chemistry and Maths. I need to view subject name in tab content when i click corresponding subjects.

It is working fine in static, Here is my static code

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-striped tabs-top theme-color">
<ion-tab title="PHYSICS">
    <ion-tab-content>
        PHYSICS
    </ion-tab-content>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="CHEMISTRY">
    <ion-tab-content>
        CHEMISTRY
    </ion-tab-content>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="BIOLOGY">
    <ion-tab-content>
        BIOLOGY
    </ion-tab-content>
</ion-tab>
```

Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Here is the controller,

```
.controller('MocktestCtrl', function($scope,$ionicLoading,$stateParams,$http,$ionicTabsDelegate,$timeout){

$ionicLoading.show({
    template: 'Loading...'
});
$scope.testName = $stateParams.testTitle;
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "http://ozternlmsio-api.azurewebsites.net/api/MockTest/GetMockTestData?mockTestId="+$stateParams.testId+"&userId="+USER_ID+"&mockTestGroupId="+$stateParams.testGroupId+"&courseId="+COURSE_ID+""
}).then(function mySucces(response) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.subjects = response.data.Subjects;

    $timeout(function(){
        $ionicTabsDelegate.select(0, true);
    }, 1000);
}, function myError(response) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
});
```

})

Comment: What's in your controller ?

Comment: Try this : `<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-striped tabs-top theme-color" ng-controller="MocktestCtrl">`

Comment: Can you show us also what is `response.data.Subjects` like?

Comment: Please see the above code. I have updated the code. In controller i am getting test data from server. Response is in json format returning subjects and its details.

Comment: What do you mean by "tab content are incorrect" ? Values are not what you expected, or undefined ?

Comment: This is the json format,

[
    {MockTestSubjectTitle: 'PHYSICS',MockTestSubjectId:'1001'},
    {MockTestSubjectTitle: 'CHEMISTRY',MockTestSubjectId:'1002'},
    {MockTestSubjectTitle: 'BIOLOGY',MockTestSubjectId:'1003'}];

Comment: When i click Tab 1st tab Physics, content should be a text 'Physics'. if i select Chemistry content should be 'Chemistry'. I just want to see, each content of tabs should be related to the subject. But in my code same content is repeating in other tabs.

Comment: It seems you're not the only one with this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139872/ionic-framework-tabs-with-ng-repeat-not-working

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible currently as there is already an open issue at Ionic repo for this. Check the link for more details: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4454